# Integrating compiler to compile C++ code and running it in Abaqus

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, abaqus

Recently, I learned that C++ codes runs faster than Python. We have post-processing Python script which takes huge time to run. So, I'm thinking of replacing them with C++ code. I know that C++ code can only be used for Post-processing, and that is fine for me.

I am not sure how to run the C++ code in Abaqus. I know that I need a compiler to compile the C++ code, like Visual Studio.  But I don't know about integrating it with Abaqus and overall flow to compile and run the script.
Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: *C++ codes runs faster than Python* sometimes. Depends a lot on how smart the code is and how well it takes advantage of what either language does well.

Comment: *C++ codes runs faster than Python* This I read in Abaqus Scripting User's Guide. Anyway, I have to confirm it.

Comment: `Visual Studio` is not C++ compiler but `IDE` which can run C++ compiler - but you still can download and install C++ compiler separatelly and run it in console without `Visual Studio`.

Comment: you can always try write C++ library and wrap it with Python so you will run Python script which will run C++ library

Comment: Thank for suggestion @furas. But, I think, as this is NOT a simple C++ code, but it has Abaqus related commands and hence, this must be integrated with Abaqus somehow.

Comment: did you search it? I used Google for `Abaqus C++` and I think I saw some answers on Stackoverflow. Something like [Reference Abaqus C++ API static libraries to read ODB files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54453524/reference-abaqus-c-api-static-libraries-to-read-odb-files)

Comment: I searched for other keywords. But I completly missed searching that way. Thank you @furas. I will get some help from this links.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235121/discussion-between-satish-thorat-and-furas).

Answer (score -1):

Recently, I have the same problem with you,if you want to use C++ you must use the script in command: abaqus make job=filename.cpp.Then abaqus will give you a file:filename.exe,I think that C++ is same as fortran,I couldn't link it to abaqus ,so I couldn't run the .exe file,if you can solve my problem I would appreciate that you could answer me.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow! In my opinion you should answer a question only if there's enough information to address the OP issue; but you are finishing with another question, and that is confusing. I think that this is more suitable for a comment, instead of a full answer as you posted.